# EF Migrations - How and when is the DB migrated down

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I have followed the MSDN process [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) for enabling migrations and I have created some test migrations that work fine (going Up).  What I'm not entirely sure of is how and when `Down()` is called.  Currently the application I am writing will be installed and the Migration takes place on application run (this all works fine)

How and when would the database be normally migrated down wards?

- On uninstall
- Does another version take care of this when run (say installing an older version after uninstall)
- Or does some other factor come in here?

If it is a manual process then how is it executed?

Comment: In the link you provide you can find how to downgrade manually to the specific migration

Comment: That only works from within VS though?

Comment: there is also the external migrate.exe tool which can run your migrations

Answer (score 0):

`Down()` is used when you have to roll back an installation and is most likely run manually in the Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Update-Database –TargetMigration:"TheNameOfLastMigrationToKeep"
```

(If your current migration is newer than the specified this makes a downgrade, otherwise it migrates your database forward to that specific migration)

In the most likely workflow you develop your application in increments and as part as your deployment you let EF automatically migrate your database from point A to point B using the `Up()` part of the migrations.

Unfortunately this doesn’t work all the time. Sometimes you find a big bug right after the deployment and now you need a clean way to get your database back to the state it had before the migration. To go from point B back to Point A you can use the `Down()` migrations or restore your database. Which one you prefer depends on your systems, your process and if you as a developer are allowed to restore a database.